Is it rational to want to die someday, because if you live forever, the probability approaches 1 that you'll fall into the center of a star?
If you were immortal, the probability that you get into an inescapable horrible situation approaches unity, right? That's the nature of the strange creature called Infinity.
For example, if you fell into the center of a star, you'd stay there and endure the light, heat, and pressure for 10 billion years until it explodes, after which, you'd become part of a black hole event horizon for trillions of years.
This concept has been used in science fiction many times, like in the Tales From The Crypt episode where a dead guy is reanimated and immortal — after he's embalmed.
It would seem that logically, one would prefer death. But that would seem equivalent to, "I don't know how it will happen, but I hope I die someday" — which is a horrible thing to want.

Yes, this is completely rational. Simone de Beauvoir's novel All Men Are Mortal is a fantastic read on this subject.


@CosmicGenis > Thank you for your understanding question. == My best guess is that this is an insult that I can't recognize because I'm autistic.


@Philomath That's an amazing story! == A billion years hence the whole world is white and dead, populated only by two living beings: he and the mouse on which he tested the immortality potion. == That's exactly like Kubrick's AI. The humans invent a robot boy that will love his mother forever. But when she realizes he can never be a real boy, she dumps him on the side of the road next to the broken robot dump. 100,000  years later, he's frozen under a glacier, immobile, still seeking his mother. The only one he can talk to is his robot teddy bear who has followed him around the whole time.

Twilight Zone epi. Guy sells soul to the Devil for immortality. He'll only die when he wants to. Goes out and does everything he wants, commits capital crimes secure in the knowledge that he can't be executed. Shocked when his death sentence is commuted to life in prison. In despair, he summons the Devil and asks for death.

@user4894 Yes! When I said this was used frequently in science fiction, that was another example I was thinking of, and there are others, too.

I’m voting to close this question because the question does not deal with a philosophical problem. I would even question that this post makes sense in any other context.

@JoWehler  The problem is explicitly a major philosophic one, the incompatibility of human psychology with statis and satisfaction.  We cannot even identify a "heaven" that would not be hellish if lived for eternity.  Modern analytic philosophy may not recognize this as philosophy, but the Greek, Chinese, and Existentialist traditions all do.

@Dcleve It also touches on a subtle philosophical point: the gap between immortality and eternity

Falling into the center of a star is probably far from the worst thing that can happen to you.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_recurrence_theorem

There are a heck of a lot more prosaic reasons to want to be mortal than not wanting to fall into the center of a star.

The probability of an event does not necessarily approach unity over a countably infinite number of trials, even if the probability of such an event is not zero.  See almost surely.

@MichaelSeifert That's the kind of answer I was looking for. One that makes sense. Post that  answer and get 10 points. == I think it's 10.

Seems to be that if you can rationalize it, then by definition under that rationale, it is rational. Whether that rationale applies depends on exact circumstances and your own personality.
Personally, I consider it irrational to actively want to die until the alternative becomes worse without reasonable hope of recovery to an adequate duration of adequate quality-of-life.
Wanting to be mortal may be more rational. But that's a trade-off; the question is whether the good aspects justify the bad, and that's darn hard to predict. If you are speculating that every disaster is possible, you have to also allow that every triumph is possible.
Note that many different degrees and kinds of "immortality" have been discussed, ranging from simply not aging to rapid healing to immunity to disease to the annoying kind where you outlive the universe and are left there hanging in not-even-nothingness quietly going mad from sensory deprivation... Or maybe not even having that escape. I think you needed to define exactly what you expect living forever would be like before you can decide whether you would want it or not.
Living forever with dementia, for example, would not be my idea of a good time.
As has been true for other speculative questions, speculative fiction has explored a lot of this. A few such stories have already been mentioned; there are many others. Since they all define the question a bit differently, and define the individual the question is applied to a bit differently, they correctly reach many different answers.

I read a story where a man with advanced dementia was given a pacemaker because the doctors felt unable to make a judgment call of what was worthwhile or in a person's best interest. The man lived on and on for years, becoming entirely insensate, and family was left with this "living dead" person, who could have died 'naturally' years before, leaving resources to care for people who could actually be helped. Can we legislate some common sense?

@ScottRowe: Out of scope for this discussion, but this is one of the reasons that you really need advance medical directives in place, along with a medical proxy. Doctors are trained, and the law is structured, to default to extending life. It is up to the patient to specify the limits of that, since each patient will draw the lines of acceptable quality and duration of life in different places. Organizations such as Compassion And Choices have provided some excellent resources to help decide and express your preferences; I strongly recommend taking advantage of them.

Continuing off topic response: I do have to note that we are often kinder to our pets in this regard then to our family, or ourselves.

Immortality comes with a cruel truth: given enough time, you’re obviously to face every possible nightmare imaginable., trapped in suffering with no way out days go by months and years In that light, mortality feels like a light., a quiet promise that even pain has an end. But wishing for death feels wrong, like betraying the very spark that makes life worth living. Maybe the beauty of being human lies in knowing that every moment, even the hard ones, is fleeting—and that’s what makes it matter.

The presumption of this question is that of physical survival.  But it applies to spiritual dualist survival as well.

If one wants to reference recent speculative fiction, the residents of The Good Place end up facing the psychological problem that humans are built for change and challenges, and TGP does not provide either.
Critics of the Christian heaven note that living without change and with nothing to do, for eternity, does not sound "heavenly".
Mystic empiricism has also found examples where this is a concern.  The lost souls found by Edith Fiore (Unquiet Dead) and Robert Monroe (Journeys out of the Body), and the Hungry Ghosts of Joseph Fisher live pointlessly forever, frustrated about their inability to engage this world.

From a spiritual dualist perspective, even if one can die in THIS world, that will not necessarily remove the problem the OP raises.
The nature of a human psyche is not able to end up in anything other than despair if our selves were to last forever.
